# Does Koukin Shuuyu play a big main role in Ikkitousen?

Tags: ikkitousen

I know that Koukin Shuuyu is "a" main character, and I know he is not the protagonist. But what I'm wondering is, does he play a big enough role in the series where he would show up in almost every episode or at least referred to.

One of my pet peeves is ecchi genre with a female protagonist. I'm a big disliker of shoujo anime. Although I know this isn't one.

I've been looking at this anime for a while, but the ratings and reviews have been keeping me at bay. The female protagonist doesn't make it any easier to swallow, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, he doesn't play much of a main character role, though he's important in the first series as someone who's there to help explain what's going on to the audience. The series/franchise focuses mainly on **Hakufu Sonsaku**, his cousin. Although he's listed as a main character in most of the shows from the franchise, so are a lot of the other fighters from the school, who don't always appear in every episode.

For example, in **Ikkitousen: Xtreme Xecutor**, it seems Shuuyu is listed as a main character but I can't remember seeing him at all in the series, if only in passing.

As for the franchise itself, and this is purely opinion, I've heard that the Battle Vixens manga that the show was adapted from is superior to the various anime. While it is in the ecchi genre, there's a lot of focus on the fighting (and clothes magically getting ripped to shreds during fights), and while very liberally taken, the background link to the Romance of the Three Kingdoms is mildly compelling.